# How to correctly eliminate some entries in a vector

Tags: amsmath, vector

I have a vector of vectors that can be described as

```
{A} &= \left(\vec{a_i}\right)_{i=1}^{N}
```

I want to discard some of its elements based on some conditions, how can formulate it?

For instance, I have:

```
{A^R}=(\vec{a} \mid \forall  \vec{a} \in {A} \wedge \vec{a} \in \mathcal{A}^R )
```

To denote the vector which only keeps the elements that are contained in the set `\mathcal{A}^R` and eliminates all other elements.

Is there a better formulation for it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I'm not sure that your question is on topic here. Seems to be more mathematics...

Comment: this is not really on topic here. you can ask how to express the notation you need in tex, but questions about what notation to use should be asked in a math site